# Pass model object back to controller from partial on ui dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an edit details form that is displayed as a partial on a jquery ui dialog. I want to commit amendments back to the database, but I have run in to trouble using the standard submit button used on MVC3 edit forms.. I want to commit the change, but remain on the dialog.

I have put button on the page that is calling a bit of jquery (below). What I need to know is how I can serialize my model (called Models.User) and pass that back to the controller.

As you can see I have the majority of the jquery in place - all I need to do is serialize and data and send it. I am guessing I will need to use Json, but im not 100% on how to bring that in.

Any help appreciated..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(function() {
            $("#quickButton1").live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Users/QuickEditSave/",
                    data: ({}),                  
                    success: function (data) {
                        uiDialog.close();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });    
</script>
```

Comment: please post complete code for your view.

Answer (score 1):

you must serialize form input elements into JSON object then send it via `$.Ajax`.

use this plugin to serialize you'r form data (this part is from an SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)):

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});​
```

and then send it with :

```
   $.ajax({
         url: "/Users/QuickEditSave/",
         data: JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()),                  
         success: function (data) {
          uiDialog.close();
         },
         error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```
var formData = $("form").serialize();

data: formData,
type: "POST",
```

then in my controller expect and object:

```
public string QuickEditSave(newUser newuser)
```

Comment: If this is the solution, you should mark it as such. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer